# jQuery Mobile Listview with more than one paragraphs

Tags: ipad, listview, jquery-mobile

I've developed a listview with items like the template below but when I'm trying to add a second paragraph below the existing one page cannot scroll on iPad. The same page on my desktop works just fine. Does anyone know how can I overcome this issue? Note that the page height is bigger than one page.

```
<ul>
  <li data-icon="carat-d">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/image1.png">
      <h2>header</h2>
      <p>paragraph1</p>
      <p>paragraph2</p> <!-- This line cause the issue -->
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you wrapping contents in _content_ div? `<div role="main" class="ui-content">`.

Comment: Yes, this is how body begins.
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

Comment: Are you wrapping listview in another listview? `role="main"` not `data-role="main"`.

Comment: No. the path is body->div data-role="page"->div data-role="main"->ul data-role="listview"-></body>

Comment: Are you setting page's height? Do you have extra CSS to override jQM's styles?

Comment: I have this line <meta name="viewport" content="width=700px, initial-scale=1"> on the <head> and the jquery stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62848/discussion-between-omar-and-swe).